# How to change the text of a <span> element using Javascript without <span> disappearing?

Tags: javascript, html, text

I have a really simple question but it's something I have not done before.

I have `<span>↑</span>` in my HTML:

```
<div class="button--up-down" data-type="up">
    <span>↑</span>
</div>
```

But I dont have `<span>↑</span>` in my JS:

```
var lastPageScroll = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.button--up-down', function () {
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    var speed = 0; //ms

    if (type == 'up') {
        lastPageScroll = $("body,html").scrollTop();
        if (lastPageScroll > 0) $(this).attr('data-type', 'down').text('↓');
        $("body,html").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, speed);
    }
    if (type == 'down') {
        $(this).attr('data-type', 'up').text('↑');
        $("body,html").animate({
            scrollTop: lastPageScroll
        }, speed);
    }
});
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    var $button_up_down = $('.button--up-down');
    var type = $button_up_down.attr('data-type');

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $button_up_down.addClass("visible");

        if (type == 'down') {
            $button_up_down.attr('data-type', 'up').text('↑');
        }
    } else if (lastPageScroll == 0 || ($button_up_down.attr('data-type') == 'up' && $(window).scrollTop() < 150)) $button_up_down.removeClass("visible");
});
```

So I need to add `<span>↑</span>` to my JS but i am not sure how to add it without using `innerHTML`?

Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: `$("#somewhere").append("<span>↑</span>")`

Comment: Instead of this: `$(this).attr('data-type', 'down').text('↓');`, try `$(this).attr('data-type', 'down').find('span').text('↓');`

Answer (score 0):

//create any element gave it an id

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

// this line of code write in onCick handler

```
let app = document.querySelector('#app');
app.append('<span></span>');
```

//use templating string if you want to set any value in span like this

```
app.append(`<span>${anyValue}</span>`);
```